# Vaadin cropfield selection stick to top

Tags: vaadin, cropfield

In vaadin application I use CropField addon to crop user's avatar. The problem is that whenever I try to test it, selection area is always stick to the top of the cropfield. Everything was fine on one page but when I copied exactly that piece of code to another page the problem has occured. Do you have any ideas why?

```
            NativeButton nb = new NativeButton("Click on me");
            layout.addComponent(nb);
            nb.addListener(new ClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    final Window window = new Window();
                    window.setModal(true);
                    DivLayout cropContent = new DivLayout();
                    window.setContent(cropContent);

                    final CropField cropField = new CropField(new ExternalResource("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg"));
                    cropField.setSelectionAspectRatio(1);
                    cropContent.addComponent(cropField);
                    //cropField.setImmediate(true);


                    NativeButton btClose = new NativeButton("Close");
                    btClose.addListener(new ClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            getMyApplication().getMainWindow().removeWindow(window);
                        }
                    });
                    cropContent.addComponent(btClose);
                    getMyApplication().getMainWindow().addWindow(window);
                }
            });
```

Comment: It turned out that it's about html template. At first I thought that cropfield is shown in a separate window where template html is not used and it doesn't depend on html. However, moving div element with Upload component to the beginning of html file eliminates this error. Anyway, this is not the solution, I didn't find any reason of this weird behavior, still searching it.

Comment: the selected area of cropfield behaves unpredictable only when there are some TextFields before it - still have no solution